# How to UPDATE 1 dropdown and 4 text filed values dynamically using ajax and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have two drop down lists and 4 text fields.
Now I want to change the value of the text field and the second dropdown based upon the first dropdowns value.

I succeed to change the value of only single portion of my website(either 2nd dropdown or text field) at a time dyanmically. I am not getting how to update all five (1+4) dynamically and simultaneously[image][image: this is php part]
[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also on what basis you want to update those *(like onclick, onload,....)*

Comment: _i succeed to change the value of only single portion_ how? can you include it? what is the `dataType` of ajax?

Comment: i have addded screen shots of both ajax and php part that i have done so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need more information, what you actually tried or not, what's working, what you get from your ajax, ... to help... But, basically, and based on the way you seem to do it (or, the way you want it to be done) your js (jquery) should look like this :

```
$(document).on('change','#yourWardSelectId',function(event){
    var currentValue = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        method : 'POST', //or get, or whatever
        url : 'whatever', //your url
        data : {'myValue':currentValue}, //the data you post
        dataType : 'json',
        success : function(dataReturned){
            //here is what you do on success
            $('#corporatorFieldId').val(dataReturned.corporator);
            $('#zoneNameFieldId').val(dataReturned.zoneName);
            $('#whateverId').val(dataReturned.whateverValue);
        },
        error : function(dataReturned){
            //handle your error
        }
    });
});
```

This is in the case where you get all your data from one ajax request...
Do not use "html" but use ".val" on your items to set inner value.

Here is a "over-simplified" php example of "whatever.php", considering you use PDO :

```
<?php
    //returns a pdo instance
    $db = connect();
    $whatIWant = $_POST['myValue'];
    //prepare statement
    $query = $db->prepare("SELECT name,town,age FROM people WHERE searchField = :val");
    $query->execute([':val'=>$whatIWant]);
    $result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    echo json_encode($result);
?>
```

This piece of php will return a json ARRAY that looks like this :

```
name    |    town    |    age
```

---

```
myName  |    myTown  |    30
```

So, in your JS part, get the values like this :

```
var name = dataReturned.name;
var town = dataReturned.town;
var age = dataReturned.age;
```

2 examples of what you can do if you want to "inspect" your returned data :

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(dataReturned));
console.log(dataReturned.responseText);
```

Comment: have a look at screenshots of ajax and php work that i have done

Comment: I already did! you have to use ".val" instead of ".html" ! these are inputs, not "fields".

Comment: how to return the values  in php for those inputs

Comment: @Guru ok you can check my answer